# TextBox right button MouseUp different behavior to left button

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

When trying to modify the text and select the contents of a TextBox on a mouse event I notice that the behaviour is different between the left and right clicks.

I am capturing the PreviewMouseDown event and I notice that when the right mouse button is pressed the cursor moves to the beginning of the TextBox and then back to the end when it is released.

This prevents the TextBox text from being selected but the same does not happen when left clicking.

Any ideas why this only happens for the right click?  Any way of preventing it?

To clarify what I'm trying to do is to increment/decrement the text of the textbox each time the user clicks in the textbox.  The selection is needed so that the user can either click to modify the text or type the explicit value they want and immediately replace the text.

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfSamples.Selection.InTextBoxWithEvent"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="InTextBox" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="focus away here" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="100" Margin="0,0,0,77"/>
        <TextBox Text="click here" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="100" ContextMenu="{x:Null}"
                 PreviewMouseDown="UIElement_OnPreviewMouseDown" 
                 PreviewMouseUp="UIElement_OnPreviewMouseUp"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class InTextBoxWithEvent
{
    public InTextBoxWithEvent()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void UIElement_OnPreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var textbox = (TextBox)sender;
        textbox.Text = DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString();
    }

    private void UIElement_OnPreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var textbox = (TextBox)sender;
        textbox.CaretIndex = 0;
        textbox.Select(0, textbox.Text.Length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why this happens?
On right click the code behind of control still tries to give focus to the context menu and thus your textbox control looses the focus.

Any way of preventing it?
Thus you will need capture the focus back to text box.

Comment: When I do that the focus never leaves the textbox

Comment: How can that be. Click on other button or text boxes in the application and the focus does do away. If you want to manually loose focus then do that in code too. The original question does not mention about focus.

Comment: Have you tried the code?  I just added the line and I can't click in the textbox above after having clicked in the bottom textbox

Comment: What is that you are trying to achieve with your code. Probably you can explain that and there could be a different approach towards it.